# No module found "sklearn" in pycharm while using a jupyter file

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

I tried to run the exact following code in pycharm while using a Jupyter file with python interpreter 3.7:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
print(iris)
```

I got an error of sklearn module not found but I have already installed scikit-learn module.
can anyone fix this problem??

Comment: you will need to install `sklearn` with `pip` or `conda`.

Comment: Please check interpreter configured for the project in `File - Settings  - Project - Project Interpreter`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that pip and python are the same versions. For example, if you run pip for 
Python 2.7, it will install the package only in 2.7, and if your python command point to 
for example, python 3.7 interpreters, will not have that package.